# Hide Specific Lines On Startup Highcharts R

Tags: r, highcharts

I have a data frame where I have 4 variables that I plot on startup of my Shiny app. However I would like to hide a few of them on startup so that "Price" is the only variable plotted. I am using highchart package.

I believe I found the java script code needed but I am not to sure how to insert it into the highchart function.

Below is my code with the current output vs the desired output. Data is at the bottom

```
data %>% hchart("line",  hcaes(x = date, y = Value, group = Variable))%>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ffx())
```

[image]

My desired output would look like this on start up:
[image]

Here is the JS code that I belive fits in my call somewhere:

```
"series: [{
           name: 'Value',
           data: '[iv30, iv60, Hvol20]',
           visible: false
        }]"
```

Here is a sample of my data:

```
 data = structure(list(date = structure(c(18180, 18179, 18178, 18177, 
    18176, 18173, 18172, 18171, 18170, 18169, 18180, 18179, 18178, 
    18177, 18176, 18173, 18172, 18171, 18170, 18169, 18180, 18179, 
    18178, 18177, 18176, 18173, 18172, 18171, 18170, 18169, 18180, 
    18179, 18178, 18177, 18176, 18173, 18172, 18171, 18170, 18169
    ), class = "Date"), Variable = c("Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", 
    "Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", "Hvol20", 
    "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", "iv30", 
    "iv30", "iv30", "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", 
    "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", "iv60", "Price", "Price", "Price", "Price", 
    "Price", "Price", "Price", "Price", "Price", "Price"), Value = c(13.95, 
    13.63, 13.46, 13.26, 12.72, 12.65, 12.03, 11.99, 11.13, 10.31, 
    13.83, 16.31, 16.71, 17.91, 15.19, 15.08, 17.87, 18.48, 15.9, 
    13.75, 14.69, 16.52, 17.09, 18.16, 16.23, 15.75, 18, 18.9, 16.76, 
    15.63, 296.7, 293.24, 291.32, 288.67, 293.08, 294.4, 290.42, 
    288.06, 293.24, 296.77)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("grouped_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(Variable = c("Hvol20", 
    "iv30", "iv60", "Price"), .rows = list(1:10, 11:20, 21:30, 31:40)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My way of doing it is not a perfect solution. Actually, this workaround is kinda funny, because your requirement seems to be really easy in R, but I am not an R developer and I know how to use the JavaScript code in R only.

I just wrote a JavaScript function that hides your first 3 series when the chart is loaded for the first time. I used JS("") function to inject my JavaScript code into R.

```
data %>% hchart("line",  hcaes(x = date, y = Value, group = Variable))%>% hc_add_theme(hc_theme_ffx()) %>%
hc_chart(
  events = list(
    load = JS("function() {
        this.series.forEach(function(series, i) {
        if (i < 3) {
            series.hide();
        }
      });
    }")
  )
)
```

It... works :D but if you need a better solution, you need someone who knows how to parse your data in R.